# what is the verbatim and implied meaning of 路过?

Tags: grammar

路过 means to pass through.
If one searches for images related to this word, one finds pictures of funny or strange situations carrying this word on them.

Answer (score 3):

It is more a internet-word,which means I have read this article picture story etc.to show an unconcerned opion of something,and it's more a humorous way to to show like it or not,I just read/see this,and then I will do my own thing (ie going home)
And It has much common of 打酱油

Answer (score 3):

路过 = I see what happened and I know what you mean, but it has nothing to do with me. Or it may simply means 'who cares?'

It is a way of expressing indifference, usually used when commenting a piece of news on the internet.

For example:

News: 'Selena Gomez Admits She's Crying: Is It Over Justin Bieber?'

Comment: 路过

For another:

News: 'US unemployment rate has dropped to XXX'

Comment: 路过